# Property 'zeroValue' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: typescript, class, object, generics, arguments

I am learning typescript,this code is related to Generics(Generic classes) and exists in docs of typescript.what is the problem?

```
class GenericNumber 
{ 
    zeroValue: T; 
    add: (x: T, y: T) => T; 
}

let myGenericNumber = new GenericNumber(); 
myGenericNumber.zeroValue = 0; 
myGenericNumber.add = function(x, y) 
{ 
    return x + y; 
};
```

> error:Property 'zeroValue' has no initializer and is not definitely
> assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)

Comment: One option is to make them optionals with "?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all the best way to share your TypeScript code is to publish it on [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiCmA7eAnAlsAcgVwLYCNUAeAFQD5oBvaAehugE8B7baXNKeAE2gHMlUGaGkRoALmjAg0AL1QBYAFDQV0OSiYA1KdngAuaCQDcS1dDBcuBgBQAPAyQA0jBwEpoAXgrGlAXyVKIPBibAwIyOhYeIQontDIAO5wApE4BMSI0ahk1q5GtPTMrOycPPwRQiLiktLqSrhhKRhpMQB06lo68HEADCaKDeGCUekorRY8HtAAZtiIwBJMiNB2zgzulKaqKMHYKMu20ADUjP2+RkA)

I think you are talking about [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-classes)

```js
// you missed generic initializer
class GenericNumber<T> { // you missed generic initializer
// here TS compiler throws error because you only defined a type of class
// property, but you did not initialize it
    zeroValue: T; 

    add: (x: T, y: T) => T;
}

let myGenericNumber = new GenericNumber<number>(); // you missed generic initializer
myGenericNumber.zeroValue = 0;
myGenericNumber.add = function (x, y) {
    return x + y; // no error
};
```

**Working example**

```js
class GenericNumber<T> {
// to get rid of  error, you can define constructor 
// which takes [zeroValue] and [add] as arguments
    constructor(public zeroValue: T, public add: (x: T, y: T) => T){
        this.zeroValue = zeroValue;
        this.add = add;
    }
}
const zeroValue = 0;
let myGenericNumber = new GenericNumber<number>(zeroValue, (a,b)=>a+b);
const result = myGenericNumber.add(40,2) // 42
```

Make sure your function don't deal with **this**, because in that case you should handle it

Comment: I also used constructor, but I probably did not define it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this typescript features in the following ways.

If you are using `TypeScript playground`, go to `TS Config` and `uncheck` the `strictPropertyInitialization`.

If you are using `typescript` in your project, in `tsconfig.json` file, disable this feature by setting `"strictPropertyInitialization": false`.